# Change checkbox size android without using XML

Tags: android, checkbox, widget

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have a checkbox that I am creating in a method call

```
public int myMethod(Context context, doThing) {
     if(doThing){
          this.checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
          do some stuff...
          return 1;
     }else{
          do something else...
          return 0;
     }
}
```

I would like to change the size of the checkbox (the actual box not the box and text combo) with a call like checkBox.setBoxSize(mySize).  setBoxSize is not a native android method.  Is it possible to do this, and if it is, how might I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create your checkBox with predefined width and height you can use this method:

```
this.checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
this.checkBox.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)); // or if your parent is RelativeLayout use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
```

**Note**, that your width and height are in pixels.

If you want to change already existing layout params, you should do something like this:

```
private void setBoxSize(CheckBox checkBox) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) checkBox.getLayoutParams(); // or RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    params.height = yourHeightInPixels;
    params.width = yourWidthInPixels;
    checkBox.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**EDIT:**
In that case, if you want to change size of the checkbox's button, you could only use one of this methods

```
checkBox.setButtonDrawable(int resId);
checkBox.setButtonDrawable(Drawable d);
```

and set the right size of your drawables. Unfortunately, Android doesn't have methods to manipulate button (as you mentioned - "box") of the checkbox.

Example of the drawable, that is using as checkbox's button:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_on" /> <!-- checked -->
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_off" />
</selector>
```

Comment: This appears to change the size of the actual checkbox.  I don't want to change the size of the checkbox, I want to change the size of the "box" that is within the checkbox.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Is it possible to change the side by replacing the box with an image?  If so how might I do that?  I had already come to the conclusion that changing the size probably wasn't possible, and if it was, was not easy to do.

Comment: checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable_instead_box); and your drawable should have the size that you want.

Comment: You can see example of the drawable in the answer

Comment: didn't completely do what I wanted, but with a little tweaking it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the layout Params for the `checkbox` like this

```
 //width and height are in pixels
 checkbox.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,height));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I spent an hour to test various combinations.